# can I write a url in a file with hyperlink?

Tags: python, file, hyperlink

Can I write a `url` address in a file in python such that if I click on the link it goes to browser? I mean is there Hyperlink in python code?

```
f=open(outputpath, 'a')
f.write(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask )
f.close
```

I wanna hyperlink `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` in the text file. Hyper link means https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Where do you want to click the link?
No links will be clickable in a text file, if you want to write a .md file that's totally possible but everything relies on the file viewer program that you use.
Same as how in some python shells you can click printed-out links and in some you can't.
Theres no way to "make a hyperlink" with just python writing to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hyperlink in a text file, but you can hyperlink in a HTML file.
Here's how to do it:

```py
f = open("file.html", 'w')
f.write("""<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'>
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
</a>""")
f.close()
```

Comment: I never worked with `htm` files. can I use mode `a` to write multiple things?

Comment: You can read more about the `<a>` tag here:   
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Answer (score 0):

Usually enclosing the link in angle brackets `<>` tells text editors and the like that it's a link. Try this:

```
f = open(outputpath, 'a')
f.write("<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask>")
f.close()
```

Notice that you need to add the parentheses onto the call to `close()`, and that you always enclose strings with quote marks `""` or `''`.